# mysql JOIN ON statement with MAX functions

Tags: mysql, join, max

I want to join a mysql table with the aggregate function on JOIN ON statement.
I am not sure I am doing it correctly.

Here are my tables. `Table_1` (has three columns):

- id
- sid
- tid

`Table_2` (has four columns)

- t2id
- t2sid
- t2tid
- t2value

`Table_3` (has two columns)

- t3id
- t3title

The first two tables, `Table_1` and `Table_2` they have the relationship on
`table_1.sid` and `table_2.t2sid`, and I have no issue joining them.
Now, I wanted to JOIN
the `table_3.t3id` to the `table_2 t2tid = 2` then `table_t2value`.

Here is what I have so far as a MySql statement:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN table2.t2tid=1 THEN table_2.t2value AS 1stid), 
       MAX(CASE WHEN table_2.t2tid=2 THEN table_2.t2value AS 2ndid)
FORM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2
ON table_2.t2sid = table_1.sid
LEFT JOIN table_3
ON table_3.t3id = (i want to join the table_2.t2tid=3 THEN table_2.t2value)
```

would I be able to join them the way I want?

Comment: "i want to join the table_2.t2tid=3 THEN table_2.t2value" - what does this mean? Can you show us your desired output?

Comment: hi EPB, I want to the table_3.t3title data into my query results. Here the how the tables are storage and related each other. table_1 and table_2 column sid that two column has the relationship. Let's say, when i query the table_1.sid and table_2.sid. i will get the following results in SELECT statement as 1stid results will be from table_2.t2value and table_2.t2value. Now i want to JOIN the table_3 table_3.t3id to the reuslts of the table_2.t2tid=3 then table_2.t2value.  Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like below?

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN table2.t2tid=1 THEN table_2.t2value AS 1stid), 
       MAX(CASE WHEN table_2.t2tid=2 THEN table_2.t2value AS 2ndid)
FORM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2
ON table_2.t2sid = table_1.sid
LEFT JOIN table_3
ON table_3.t3id = (case when table_2.t2tid=3 THEN table_2.t2value else null end)
```

Comment: Harsh, when i added the (case when) as you stated i couldn't get the result of the table_3.t3title result.